# Spring4D - How to resolve from container with TComponent parameter to auto factory

Tags: delphi, dependency-injection, spring4d

For an example I would like to resolve a class passing in a TComponent and TNotifyEvent such as below but the base constructor of TObject gets called and not of TMy.

```
GlobalContainer.RegisterType<TMy>;
GlobalContainer.RegisterFactory<Func<TComponent,TNotifyEvent,TMy>>(TParamResolution.ByType);
var F:=GlobalContainer.Resolve<Func<TComponent,TNotifyEvent,TMy>>;
F(Self,Self.OnActivate);
```

I can get around the issue by writing some very ugly code as below but think that this kind of resolution would be so common that I must be doing something wrong.

```
    TOther = class
    end;
    
    TMy = class
    public
      constructor Create(C: TComponent; N: TNotifyEvent; O: TOther);
    end;
    
    procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    begin
      GlobalContainer.RegisterType<TOther>;
      GlobalContainer.RegisterType<TMy>;
    
      GlobalContainer.RegisterType<Func<TComponent,TNotifyEvent,TMy>>(
        function: Func<TComponent,TNotifyEvent,TMy>
        begin
          Result:=Func<TComponent,TNotifyEvent,TMy>(
            function(O: TComponent; N: TNotifyEVent): TMy
            begin
              Result:=TMy.Create(O,N,GlobalContainer.Resolve<TOther>);
            end
          );
        end
      );
      GlobalContainer.Build;
      var F:=GlobalContainer.Resolve<Func<TComponent,TNotifyEvent,TMy>>;
      F(Self,Self.OnActivate);
    end;

constructor TMy.Create(C: TComponent; N: TNotifyEvent; O: TOther);
begin
  OutputDebugString('Resolved');
end;
```

Thanks in advance for any pointers.

Comment: Not sure which version you are using but this works just fine with the latest develop

Comment: "_Thanks in advance for any pointers_" - better not. Leave pointers to those who grew up with them.

Comment: @StefanGlienke I must be missing a unit or something as I have just got the latest develop branch and it does not call the constructor with the arguments.  I have Spring, Spring.Container and Spring.Container.Common.

Comment: Ah, I see - I did try not in the context of a TForm and passed a TComponent as first parameter which did exactly match. When passing Self however it's not a direct match although it satisfies the TComponent parameter - I will look for a fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work now after the latest commit in develop.

The issue was the typed parameter resolution was bound to the argument type instead of the parameter type. In this case, this resulted in a typed value with type `TForm2` (taken from the argument being passed) which did not match the type of the C argument of the constructor of type `TComponent` because that matching checks for type identity and not assignment compatibility.

After the fix typed parameter resolution works exactly on the parameter types of the factory function instead of the possibly (in case of objects) more narrow actual type of the argument.

FWIW for future reference - when registering a factory manually it's usually not necessary to use `RegisterType` providing the delegate but can directly use `RegisterInstance` like so (keep in mind that `Spring.Func<...> has` const` parameters) when it does not have any captured state:

```
GlobalContainer.RegisterInstance<Func<TComponent,TNotifyEvent,TMy>>(
  function(const O: TComponent; const N: TNotifyEVent): TMy
  begin
    // ....
  end);
```

Edit: I also added automatic detection for the best parameter resolution default. When the factory type is a `Spring.Func<...>` it automatically uses `ByType` so it can omitted from the `RegisterFactory` call. For all other types it uses `ByName` as default as before.